# Trying to get coordinates of a JButton when clicked

Tags: java

I'm using the following code in order to create a grid of JButtons and change their color on click. The next step I want to do is be able to compare this grid with other grids like it. I have been trying to get the coordinates of the JButton when clicked, (x, y), but have been unable to find a way to do so. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
public class ButtonGrid {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates frame
  JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons
  HashMap<JButton, String> state;
  static int WIDTH = 8;
  static int LENGTH = 8;

  public ButtonGrid(int width, int length) { //constructor
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length)); //set layout
    grid = new JButton[width][length]; //allocate the size of grid
    state = new HashMap<JButton, String>();

    for(int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        final JButton nb = new JButton();//new ButtonColor; //creates a button
        nb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        grid[x][y] = nb;
        state.put(grid[x][y], "blank");

        nb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(state.get(nb).equals("blank"))
              mapButtonToColor(nb, "red");
            else if(state.get(nb).equals("red"))
              mapButtonToColor(nb, "blank");
            setButtonColors();
          }
        });
        frame.add(grid[x][y]); //adds new button to grid
      }
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
    frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonGrid(WIDTH, LENGTH);
  }

  public void mapButtonToColor(JButton b, String c) {
    state.put(b, c);
  }

  public void setButtonColors() {
    for(JButton b  : state.keySet()) {
      Color c = state.get(b).equals("red") ? Color.black : Color.white;
      b.setBackground(c);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe this will help you:

when a button is pressed in the said grid, simple iterate it to find the button that was clicked, then return the coordinates, something like this:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object source = e.getSource();
        for(int i = 0;i< grid.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0;j < grid.length;j++){
                if(source == grid[i][j]){
                    JButton clicked == grid[i][j];
                    // do something with this 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I be putting this in the existing ActionListener or creating an entirely new one? Also, I am getting an error on the return line stating that void methods cannot return a value.

Comment: well it depends, if you want to remake the ActionListener or just add this. Nevertheless the ActionListener should be doing what you want it to do when a button is clicked, if you only want to get the coordinates of the button, then this would be enough i would say

Comment: Ok thanks, any info on why I am getting the error on the return line?

Comment: oh yes, the return line is only pseudo-code, currently the code above is a method defined with void, meanning it returns nothing, either you to change that or store the coordinates somewhere you can later use them.

Comment: no problem, if it helped you solve the problem you can mark my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: Isn't this an inefficient algorithm? O(n^2) (I would say average case) seems unneeded just to find a location of a button click in a JFrame.

Comment: well, i never said it was the most efficient solution, but it is a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just implement a MouseListener?

```
yourButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          int x=e.getX();
          int y=e.getY();
          System.out.println(x+","+y);
    }
 });
```

This should do what you need as far as getting coordinates whenever your button is clicked. Also you could set the listener on your JFrame component to find the coordinate for every click (if that is needed).